# How to clear MemSQL data cache without restart cluster?

Tags: singlestore

The purpose for this question is we need to benchmark MemSQL performance in various workloads with different query and/or memsql optimization settings. So we need to avoid the impact from data caching from MemSQL.

The closest thing for this purpose I find out so far is `drop all from plancache`. But this from its words sounds like it only clear the **compiled execution plans** from MemSQL, not data cache itself. The MySQL cache clearing commands do not work on MemSQL.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sorts of data caching are you interested in clearing?

To help me understand what types of cache clearing you are interested in, which MySQL cache clearing commands were you trying to use?

MemSQL doesn't do much caching of data. The main one is caching columnstore data in memory. If you want to test the performance of queries against cold data on disk, you can flush the disk cache with:

`echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: thank for sharing the background info. I don't know the approach how MemSQL does data caching behind the scene. But I do know it dramatically improve query performance for many folds starting from the second run. I will try your command. Besides this, are there other places that I should check so that I can achieve the same effect like restarting MemSQL?

Comment: It looks like the command did the trick. I hope you can also share a few docs links so that I can learn more about the caching mechanism and how I can manage or tune its behavior.

Comment: Looking at your answer again, I see the command is only for *columnstore data*. How about the in-memory row based data? The 2nd run of a query for row table runs very fast, how can I clear those cache?

Comment: "But I do know it dramatically improve query performance for many folds starting from the second run." That is due to the first run requiring plan compilation. This is unrelated to caching query results (which memsql doesn't do) or data. See https://docs.memsql.com/introduction/latest/memsql-faq/#why-do-memsql-queries-typically-run-faster-the-second-time-they-are-executed

Comment: Most of the time, if you care about the performance of queries run multiple times, not just once, the runtime you want to benchmark is the runtime after the plan has already been compiled, i.e. after the first run. Also note that after restarting MemSQL, the plan will still be there, so it will still be fast. And if you do want to test the performance of the query including plan compilation, `drop all from plancache` will do the trick.